# JBoss 7 as operation unstable

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I have build jboss (jboss - as 7.1.1) in os linux (CentOS 5.8)
    I reload jboss with cli unstable:
    [standalone@localhost:9999 /] :reload
    Communication error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:Operation failed
    [disconnected /] connect
    [standalone@localhost:9999 /] :reload
    Communication error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:Operation failed
    [disconnected /] connect
    [standalone@localhost:9999 /] :reload
    {"outcome" => "success"}
    I have jdk 7 và jce policy 7.
    I have problem same with jboss eap 6.
    What was the problem? And how could I fix it?
     Hope to receive the support from you soon.

Comment: I have also found the JBoss CLI is not reliable for stop and restart operations. It works to configure an environment, but the the management listener sometimes stops responding, and then you need to revert to killing the jboss instance using native operating system facilities (i.e. a bash script).

Comment: i have use jdk: 
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode). 
I do not what to configure JBoss. 
uzip and run only standalone.sh. Can you tell me where I was wrong? 
Thank you